# What is real meaning behind this easy printf output in c?

Tags: c, memory

look at the two line c code and output:
code:

```
char * str = "hello world!";
printf("h at heap memory address: %p\n",str);
printf("str pointer stack memory address: %p\n",&str);
```

and output:

```
h at heap memory address: 0x4008a8
str pointer stack memory address: 0x7ffc9e7ceb90
```

the memory address length for heap and stack is  0x4008a8, 0x7ffc9e7ceb90 respectively. Why memory address for heap is 3 bytes whereas memory address for stack is 6 bytes? Something related to virtual memory and paging ?

Comment: `0x4008a8` can have as as many leading 0's in front as is necessary to fill out the address the width of a pointer

Comment: @MichaelPetch don't think so, every try will get the same 3 bytes length in heap.

Comment: The question is vague. I read it that there are 2 questions. He seems uncertain why  `0x4008a8` is 3 bytes. Internally both pointers will be the same width. The other question appears to be about the layout of user space as it relates to the stack/heap/code. Both are pointers nonetheless.

Comment: 'Heap' is usually reserved for referencing the data allocated by `malloc()` and friends.  The string literal is probably stored in the code segment, where it will be non-writable.  Ultimately, there's no 'reason' for the addresses other than 'that is where the implementation stored the items whose addresses you are printing'.  What did you expect?  Why do you think there's a problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

Comment: For 64-bit Windows, this MSDN documentation might be of interest: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439648(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Did you expect the *real meaning of it all* to print as `42` ?

Comment: Presumably addresses on your system are 64 bits. `printf` formats address without leading zeros. Think of them as `0x00000000004008a8` and `0x00007ffc9e7ceb90`. They're both 8 bytes; they just happen to have different values, indicating that they're in different regions of the virtual memory space.

Comment: @chqrlie I need some Babel Fish to translate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JohnathanLeffler nailed it.  *"The string literal is probably stored in the <strike>code</strike> [data] segment, where it will be non-writable."*  You can see this with a little more probing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Do this in a function so I can verify what is stack and what is heap.
 * Try to return a variable and see if the compiler warns that it's
 * stack memory!
 */
static char *test_mem() {
    char *stack = "whom";
    char *heap = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);

    printf("char *stack = \"%s\" at %p (size %zu) inner %p (size %zu)\n",
           stack, stack, sizeof(stack), &stack, sizeof(&stack));
    printf("char *heap = malloc at %p (size %zu) inner %p (size %zu)\n",
           heap, sizeof(heap), &heap, sizeof(&heap));

    return heap;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *ret = test_mem();
    printf("%s\n", ret);
    return 0;
}

char *stack = "whom" at 0x102fc0f28 (size 8) inner 0x7fff5cc3f4d8 (size 8)
char *heap = malloc at 0x7f9362404c80 (size 8) inner 0x7fff5cc3f4d0 (size 8)
```

Note that *only the string literal is in the lower memory address*.  All the rest are in basically the same location.  When I open up the executable in a hex editor I can find a block of strings.

```
00000f20: dcff ffff 2573 0a00 7768 6f6d 0063 6861  ....%s..whom.cha
00000f30: 7220 2a73 7461 636b 203d 2022 2573 2220  r *stack = "%s" 
00000f40: 6174 2025 7020 2873 697a 6520 257a 7529  at %p (size %zu)
00000f50: 2069 6e6e 6572 2025 7020 2873 697a 6520   inner %p (size 
00000f60: 257a 7529 0a00 6368 6172 202a 6865 6170  %zu)..char *heap
00000f70: 203d 206d 616c 6c6f 6320 6174 2025 7020   = malloc at %p 
00000f80: 2873 697a 6520 257a 7529 2069 6e6e 6572  (size %zu) inner
00000f90: 2025 7020 2873 697a 6520 257a 7529 0a00   %p (size %zu)..
```

The string `foo` is not stored in the heap, it is in the [data segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) of the executable which, as you guessed, is accessed as [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) which is allocated a special range.

Finally, the output shows those pointers are all of the same size.  They're all (in my case) 64 bit (8 byte) pointers.

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead:

```
char * str = "hello world!";
printf("h at heap memory address: %p (%zu bytes)\n", str, sizeof(str));
printf("str pointer stack memory address: %p (%zu bytes)\n", &str, sizeof(&str));
```

Using the `sizeof` operator, we can print the actual size of the two pointers. (`%zu` is a format specifier for an unsigned result from `sizeof`—it is probably equivalent to `%lu` on your system.)

You'll see that in both cases, the pointer actually takes up 8 bytes (64 bits).

The reason that the hexidecimal representations displayed by `printf` only show 3 or 6 bytes is because `printf` drops any leading zeros. Consider this similar example:

```
int i = 10;
printf("%x\n", i);
```

The result will just be "a", but that doesn't mean that `i` only takes up one byte.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

Note that pointers are still variables in C and the only thing that makes them special is that they have the special `*` notation beside them. The value of a pointer is the address it refers to, just like the value of an int is the value it is assigned to

```
char * str = "hello world!";
printf("h at heap memory address: %p\n",str);
printf("str pointer stack memory address: %p\n",&str);
```

They both use the pointer specifier (`%p`) which is used to print memory address of a value. **Note this is implementation defined.**

- The first one prints the memory address of the string literal "hello world!", i.e. the value of the pointer `str`
- The second prints the memory address of the pointer i.e. the memory address of `str`

As for why these values are so far apart, [@DaoWen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34257676/2089675) already answered this and it has nothing to do with virtual pages or whatnot.

Comment: Clean and simple.  Expand just a little bit to explain how these 2 addresses can appear so far apart.

Comment: "*As for why these values are so far apart... it has nothing to do with virtual pages or whatnot.*" This is incorrect. The constant string `"hello world!"` is in the data segment of the executable. `str`'s address is so different because it points to that section of virtual memory

Comment: @Schwern What I meant is that the answer I referred to did not mention virtual pages as the reason why they are so far apart

Comment: @Smac89 Yes, that answer doesn't address why they're far apart at all. Only that they're all the same size pointer. [I cover why they're so far apart](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34257756/14660).